# Google Geocoder unavailable on Android 2.3.1?

Tags: android, google-geocoder

Is anyone getting a `Service Not Available` Exception for every request sent to the Google Geocoder on devices running Gingerbread?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is still an open bug with this, at least using the emulator.

See this issue http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816

Someone has suggested a workaround on the above link also

Comment: I am aware of  that bug but as far as I know it was related only to  emulators...